# Google Mobile Usability Still Viewport not configured

Tags: mobile, viewport, google-search-console

Viewport not configured but I have this code:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

I test https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/mobile-friendly/ and it says, "Awesome!

The tool says it is mobile-friendly, but meanwhile in Google Mobile Usability the error is still there.

I fixed the issue in May 2015
Latest Status: 6/14/15

Answer (score 3):

For webmaster tools, the tag should end with `/>` and be the first one in the header:

```
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
```

Comment: Not for HTML 4.01 transitional it shouldn't